# Multiple map activities in an application

Tags: android, dictionary

I'm having a bit of a problem with my Android application. I have 2 activities (among many others) which are Map activities.

The problem is that whenever I call the 2nd map activity and if the map view changes from that which was on the 1st map activity, the app crashes when returning to the first.
Well not really crash, since it's not a force close, but the map in the 1st activity is non-existant...just grey squares...the only part visible is the one that was cached from before the 2nd map activity was called.

How to fix this? Logcat shows Illegal State Exception: Connection pool shutdown and then floods the log with similar warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be avoided if you change process name in the second map activity, although this prevents you from using parameters passed to it from the rest of the app.

Comment: This works, and any parameters that is passed through Intents are not lost. So you can still pass data around.